# Android ANR Debug help

Tags: android

So my app has been immediately giving an ANR when one of my classes is run. Ive been looking through the debugger and trying to understand what is going on. I'm new to android, and have zero experienced debugging. So if anyone could help me make sense of what is going on that would be great.

My onCreate():
http://pastebin.com/QzT5KA0L

My GuiThreader(used in onCreate):
http://pastebin.com/VCp7KegY

Here is what shows up on my Debug tab when the app fails:

```
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord) line: 2268  
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord) line: 2284   
ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord) line: 112 
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1692  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 123 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3948    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 782  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 540 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: could you show us your onCreate()?

Answer (score 0):

The game loop should be in a thread of his own. I have no experience about this kind of things, but Android expects the `onCreate()` method to end in short time, because that runs on the main/UI thread, which should remain free to manage the application lifecycle.